# Prestashop 1.7.5.1 doesnt show product pictures on the frontend

Tags: prestashop

Please, help me with this issue. I have installed prestashop 1.7.5.1 and uploaded products with pictures. All pictures on the backend are displayed. But they are not displayed on the front-end.

I have tried to:

- Delete & regenerate .htaccess file with 'Seo-friendly url' http://prntscr.com/u6z00p , but it didn't help.
- Regenerate thumbnails and it didn't help too.

BTW: When i disable this option 'Friendly URLs' http://prntscr.com/u6z0ny, the product pictures are displayed on front-end. But i really need this option enabled, because i need special links of my pages.

We'll be grateful for any help ! Thanks.

Comment: is it a nginx server?

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable `mod_rewrite` in apache.
In your terminal, as root:

```
a2enmod rewrite
service apache2 restart
```